# Which Android sensors are redundant?

Tags: android, sensors, android-sensors

I'm recording the following sensor values from my tablet (given as constants of the `Sensor` class):

```
TYPE_ACCELEROMETER
TYPE_GRAVITY
TYPE_GYROSCOPE
TYPE_LIGHT
TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION
TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD
TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR
```

The problem is that I'm producing too much data. That's why I want to use less sensors. I think some sensors are redundant, i.e. can be computed from other sensor values. For example I think linear acceleration and gravity will give accelerometer and perhaps the rotation vector can be computed from linear acceleration and gyroscope (how?).

Which sensors are redundant? I'm guessing that accelerometer (or linear acceleration) as well as the rotation vector are redundant. Moreover, can the magnetic field be used for the computation of other measures (like the rotation vector)? I don't need the magnetic field value on its own, so perhaps I can also throw it out.

Edit: I think it holds that accelerometer = gravity + linear acceleration. Does this mean that gravity and linear acceleration correlates with the accelerometer? Correlated features would be useless as input to my machine learning pipeline.

I guess that rotation vector is computed with the help of the magnetic field but my magnetic field sensor has low accuracy (reported by Android), so I could drop magnetic field as well as rotation vector.

Comment: For anything other than a novice "I want to see what sensors say" app, you don't request all of them.  You request only the ones your app actually needs.  So what are you trying to do, that determines which sensors you should care about.

Comment: @GabeSechan I will use the sensors as input (features) to a machine learning pipeline for prediction of behavior of users.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have updated my question

Comment: Personally I think performing computations during sensors updating would slow down the speed of updates themselves. Also, as I've understood, you don't need some of them. For example, the rotation vector sensor is useful for games. Instead, light, accelerometer and gyroscope sensors are more suitable to take data about user's habits. In addition, light sensor isn't as expensive as others in terms of memory using.

Comment: You're backwards on your accelerometer-  accelerometer is the raw reading.  Gravity and linear_acceleration are calculated from it.